# How to spin an independent dispacher thread for a Silverlight UserControl

Tags: silverlight, multithreading

I am trying to move a lot of different elements by 1 pixel very often and in parallel. Trying to do this on one dispatcher thread means that the elements are visited one after another. The result is that the more elements I have the slower they will all move.

In WPF I was able to use a `HostVisual` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dwayneneed/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual) to solve this.

I can't seem to find anything similar in Silverlight. Is this a drawback of the lightweight framework or is there something I haven't stumbled upon yet?

I am using SL4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight only has the single user interface (primary dispatcher) thread. So yes, a drawback of the lightweight framework.

Consider if you could batch up work that you do using a BackgroundWorker, so that you can do any and all non-visual work on another thread.

Comment: You did answer my question even though it wasn't the answer I was hoping for :(. Thanks.